# in C# line 21 it keeps saying cannot use local variable 'year' before it is declared

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project_1
```

{
internal class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

```
            Console.Write("What is your name: ");
            int name = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine() );
            Console.WriteLine("Hi " + name );
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("What is your age: ");
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("WoW " + name + " you were born in " + year - age);
            int year = 2022;
            year = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine() );
        

            Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}
in C# line 21 it keeps saying cannot use local variable 'year'  before it is declared

Comment: Why is name declared as int? In any case, that code isnt safe, convert will throw if an int cant be parsed from the readline calls.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the `year` variable on this line:

```
int year = 2022;
```

But you are trying to use it on the line before that:

```
Console.WriteLine("WoW " + name + " you were born in " + year - age);
```

You need to move the declaration to the line before you use the variable.